# Jquery/Ajax - XML Parsing - extract record according to criteria

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, parsing, xml-parsing

Is it possible to extract records from xml that match a query string criteria?

For example I have the following parse script that parses a xml file,  the page url can contain several different query strings such as music -   would it be possible to read the query string and then only parse records that match the phrase in the query string?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
url: "#",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {

    $(xml).find("catalogueResult").each(function(i) {

        var mediaArtist = $("artist", this).text()
        var imgSrc   = $("imageUrl", this).text()
        var title = $("title", this).text()
        var priceCode = $("priceCode", this).text()
        var mediaRow= $('<div class="mediaBlock"><div class="promoImg floL"><img src="'+imgSrc+'" width="75" alt="'+title+'"/></div><div class="promoContent"><h2>'+title+'</h2><h2 class="red">'+mediaArtist+'</h2><div class="buyBtn"><span><A href="http://www.mobilechilli.com">Buy Now</a></span></div></div></div>');
        var compiledData = $(mediaRow);
        $(".recommends").append(compiledData);

    });
}
```

});

Comment: I noticed that you're doing these `$('` `);` before strings? I don't think you have to do that. You also added `(i)` for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this. Although you may have to change some variables according to how you've structured your xml.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "( URL to your xml )",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: parseXml
});


// function that parses XML
function parseXml(xml){

    // find node with name "catalogueResult" and run function for each
    $(xml).find("catalogueResult").each(function(){

    // variables
    var mediaArtist = $(this).find("artist").text();
    var imgSrc = $(this).find("imageUrl").text();
    var title = $(this).find("title").text();

    var priceCode = $(this).find("priceCode").text();
    var mediaRow= '<div class="mediaBlock"><div class="promoImg floL"><img src="'+imgSrc+'" width="75" alt="'+title+'"/></div><div class="promoContent"><h2>'+title+'</h2><h2 class="red">'+mediaArtist+'</h2><div class="buyBtn"><span><A href="http://www.mobilechilli.com">Buy Now</a></span></div></div></div>';

    $(".recommends").append(mediaRow);

    });
}
```